# How to avoid UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I have to test some JSON/RPC based web app with different combinations of values. Some values cause error (as expected). Now I just want to continue my testing with saving of error/exception (throws during execution). For example as per given code

```
    const abcWeb = require('abc-web');
const abcWeb = new abcWeb('http://testnet-jsonrpc.abc-xyz.org:12537');

const abTx = require('abc-transaction');
var n = 12;
var gp = 10;
var gl = 21000;
var to = '5989d50787787b7e7';
var value = 70;
var limit = 4;
var i=1;
while (i<limit){

  try{
const tx = new abTx({
    n: n,
    gp: gp,
    gl:gl , 
    to: to, 
    value:value ,
  });

    abTx.sign(Buffer.from('8f2016c58e898238dd5b4e00', 'hex'));
    abcWeb.abx.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex'));
    console.log(abTx);

  } catch (exception) {
    var message = exception.message;
    console.log(message);
    continue;

  }
  finally {
    i++;
    n +=1;
    gp +=1;
    gl +=1;
    abcWeb.abx.getENumber().then(console.log);
  }
}
```

But when UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error occurred, node will stop execution. Is it possible to bypass UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error ? How to make a loop of for such errors to skip ? UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error normally comes after sign function and/or sendSignedTransaction.. I just want to bypass it.

Comment: easy, handle rejections (`.catch` is the way to go)

Comment: @Bravo would elaborate with simple example .. as i am totally newbie .. thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your ACTUAL code and we can help you more specifically.  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is caused by a promise that rejects without a `.catch()` handler on it.  You need to show us the relevant code.

Comment: I have edited my question with my code..

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error normally comes after sign function and/or sendSignedTransaction.. I just want to bypass it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an handler for the `unhandledRejection` event:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  // handle error ... or don't
});
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amit you solved my problem.. However, it come with another problem, if you would solve it, i shall be very thankful.. the problem.. the process.on called three times rather than one time (because i know my error will come only one time ) as per my following code 
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

  try{
...

  } catch (exception) {
    .....
  }
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', error  => {
  console.log("Rejected due to  ",error)
})

Rejected due to   Error: 
Rejected due to   Error: 
Rejected due to   Error:

Comment: please use process.on('unhandledRejection') outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`catch (err)` cannot catch `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error from Promise when you use `.then()`. You can either change it to `await myPromise()` style or you can `.catch` a promise.

Example: this will throw error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```js
async function test() {
    throw new Error()
}

;(async function main() {
    try {
        test().then(console.log)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('caught it', err);
    }
})()
```

This will not:

```js
async function test() {
    throw new Error()
}

;(async function main() {
    try {
        test().then(console.log)
            .catch(() => {})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('caught it', err);
    }
})()
```

This also will not

```js
async function test() {
    throw new Error()
}

;(async function main() {
    try {
        await test()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('caught it', err);
    }
})()
```

Comment: But I have no main function and not even any function... so, in my case @Tuan could you help me to find out where should i put such keyword 'async'  (keeping in view my updated question with code)